# Upload dSYMS to Firebase via Fastlane

Tags: firebase, continuous-integration, fastlane

I am struggling to upload dSYM files to Firebase via Fastlane.  I have a lane that looks like the following:

```
desc "Fetch and upload dSYM files to Firebase Crashlytics"
lane :refresh_dsyms_firebase do |options|
  download_dsyms(version: options[:version])        
  upload_symbols_to_crashlytics(gsp_path: "./App/GoogleService-Info.plist") 
  clean_build_artifacts
end
```

I confirmed that that is the correct path to the `plist` file, but when I try to run the lane at first I see the following:

```
[17:22:47]: invalid byte sequence in UTF-8
[17:22:47]: invalid byte sequence in UTF-8
[17:22:47]: invalid byte sequence in UTF-8
```

and then one of these for every dSYM file found:

```
[17:22:48]: Uploading '70DBE65E-227E-3754-89F2-EEFA6B8EEC2F.dSYM'...
[17:22:48]: Shell command exited with exit status  instead of 0.
```

I am trying to determine exactly what I am missing from this process.  Does anyone have ideas?  I am fairly new to Fastlane, so definitely assume I could be missing something basic. (Although, that empty exit status is a bit weird).

fastlane 2.107.0

EDIT(June 7th: 2021):
I updated the answer from my own to one that was helpful to me at the time this was written.

There are many other great answers on this page on using Fastlane as well - please check them out

Comment: I'm experiencing the same issue, any updates on this?

Comment: @Broco nope. still happening.  there should be a github issue for fastlane about something similar i commented on

Comment: Any update on this?

Comment: @EvertonCunha see the answer i just added

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This may not be an option for most, but I just ended up fixing this by starting over. It may not be entirely obvious if you came over from Fabric, but I figured I would just rip off the band aid. My original setup was using the Fabric(Answers)/Firebase Crashlytics which is the Fabric->Firebase migration path, although subtle, the configuration between the two are slightly different and cause issues with `upload_symbols_to_crashlytics`

1. Remove support for Fabric answers, or replace with https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/ios/start
2. Remove the `Fabric` declaration in `Info.plist`
3. Modify your existing run script in BuildPhases: replace your existing runscript with `"${PODS_ROOT}/Fabric/run"` and add `$(BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR)/$(INFOPLIST_PATH)` to input files
4. In you `AppDelegate` remove `Fabric.with([Crashlytics.self])` and you can also kill the `import Fabric` as this is now covered by Firebase
5. Unlink fabric, re-onboard Firebase crashlytics, and select new integration.

```rb
desc "Upload any dsyms in the current directory to crashlytics"
lane :upload_dsyms do |options|
  download_dsyms(version: version_number, build_number: build_number)
  upload_symbols_to_crashlytics(gsp_path: "./App/Resources/GoogleService-Info.plist")
  clean_build_artifacts
end
```

Comment: Gonna give this a try - if it works i'll switch the correct answer to yours.  Just a quick clarity, did you mean to say remove `import firebase` or remove `import fabric`?

Comment: Opps, import fabric, fixing now

Comment: It's basically purging the awkward bridged integration and starting fresh. If you aren't using Answers, it's not a huge deal and greatly simplifies configuration. The legacy fabric environment variable was causing an incorrect branch in fastlane, but instead of hacking around it, I decided an unbridged "Firebase 1st" install was the right move. I've dropped my dependency on Answers long ago, so this bridge was just adding unnecessary complexity.

Comment: Wait, Ryan, will this break any production builds already out from reporting correctly?

Comment: @daredevil1234 negative, you just won't see them in your firebase dashboard. I have legacy fabric in the wild, no issues. I made sure to run inventory before i unlinked, so I was aware of all the existing crashes. Basically they were never reporting to firebase in the first place, they were being bridged between services

Answer (score 9):

anyone interested in this can follow the thread here: https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/issues/13096

TL;DR: When you call

`upload_symbols_to_crashlytics(gsp_path: "./App/GoogleService-Info.plist")`

It will call a binary from the installed Fabric pod called `upload_symbols` and will look something like this:

`./Pods/Fabric/upload-symbols -a db4d085462b3cd8e3ac3b50f118e273f077497b0 -gsp ./App/GoogleService-Info.plist -p ios /private/var/folders/x1/x6nqt4997t38zr9x7zwz72kh0000gn/T/d30181115-8238-1fr38bo/D4CE43B9-9350-3FEE-9E71-9E31T39080CD.dSYM`

You'll notice that it calls it using both the Fabric API key and the GoogleService-Info.plist path.  I do not know why but this will cause it not to upload.  You'll have to temporarily remove the fabric configuration information from your `Info.plist` file before running the fastlane lane.  (remember to re-add the fabric configuration).

Answer (score 5):

First, you need to use `upload_symbols_to_crashlytics` but before to use it you will need to download your dsyms from App Store Connect and to do that you should use `download_dsyms` with some parameters `version` and `build_number` and the Fastlane will ask you about your `app_identifier` so I advise you to use it to not interrupt the build until getting your answer.

```
desc "Upload any dsyms in the current directory to Crashlytics of firebase"
lane :upload_dsyms do |options|

  version_number = get_version_number(target: "your_app_target")
  build_number = get_build_number
  download_dsyms(
    app_identifier: "your_app_identifier",
    version: version_number,
    build_number: build_number
  )
  upload_symbols_to_crashlytics(gsp_path: "./your_app_name or your_app_target/another_directroy/GoogleService-Info.plist")
  clean_build_artifacts
end
```

my app was

```
desc "Upload any dsyms in the current directory to Crashlytics of firebase"
lane :upload_dsyms do |options|

  version_number = get_version_number(target: "Movies")
  build_number = get_build_number
  download_dsyms(
    app_identifier: "com.vngrs.Movies.demo",
    version: version_number,
    build_number: build_number
  )
  upload_symbols_to_crashlytics(gsp_path: "./Movies/Resources/GoogleService-Info.plist")
  clean_build_artifacts
end
```

Answer (score 2):

### Details

- Xcode Version 11.3.1 (11C504)
- Firebase tools 7.14.0
- Fastlane 2.143.0

### Solution

> ./fastlane/Pluginfile

```
gem 'fastlane-plugin-firebase_app_distribution'
```

> Lane

```
before_all do
    # Update fastlane
    update_fastlane
    # Update fastlane plugins
    sh("fastlane update_plugins")
    # Update firebase tools
    sh("curl -sL firebase.tools | upgrade=true bash")
end
```

### Usage 1.

> Download dsyms from AppStore and upload to firebase

```
download_dsyms(version: '1.0', build_number: '1')
upload_symbols_to_crashlytics(gsp_path: "./App/Environment/production/GoogleService-Info-production.plist")
```

### Usage 2.

> Get dsyms from archive (after build) and upload to firebase

```
gym(
    configuration: 'Release',
    scheme: 'MyApp',
    include_bitcode: true
   )
upload_symbols_to_crashlytics(gsp_path: "./App/Environment/production/GoogleService-Info-production.plist")
```

### Info

- [get_version_number](https://docs.fastlane.tools/actions/get_version_number/#get_version_number)
- [download_dsyms](https://docs.fastlane.tools/actions/download_dsyms/#download_dsyms)
- [sh](https://docs.fastlane.tools/actions/sh/#sh)
- [update_fastlane](https://docs.fastlane.tools/actions/update_fastlane/#update_fastlane)
- [upload_symbols_to_crashlytics](https://docs.fastlane.tools/actions/upload_symbols_to_crashlytics/#upload_symbols_to_crashlytics)

Answer (score 1):

This works for me.

**1. Create a new lane on Fastfile**

```ruby
# Fastfile
default_platform(:ios)

# Constants
XCODE_PROJECT = "PROJECT.xcodeproj"
XCODE_WORKSPACE = "PROJECT.xcworkspace"
PRODUCTION_GSP_PATH = "./APP_ROOT/GoogleService-Info.plist"


platform :ios do
  desc "Push a production build to TestFlight"
  lane :upload_crashlytics_prod do 
    download_dsyms(
        version: get_version_number(xcodeproj: XCODE_PROJECT), 
        build_number: get_build_number(xcodeproj: XCODE_PROJECT)
    )
    upload_symbols_to_crashlytics(gsp_path: PRODUCTION_GSP_PATH)
  end
end
```

**2. Now call from your shell script or terminal**

```ruby
fastlane upload_crashlytics_prod
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

```
  desc "Downlaod and Uplaod dSYMS to Firebase"
  lane :uplaod_dsyms do 
  download_dsyms # This will download all version 
  upload_symbols_to_crashlytics(
      gsp_path: "Path to your google plist",
      binary_path: "./Pods/FirebaseCrashlytics/upload-symbols") # this goes to cocoapods of FirebaseCrashlytics 
  clean_build_artifacts # Delete the local dSYM files 
 end
```